# Force NLog to create a new log folder for year, month and day

Tags: configuration, nlog

How can I force NLog to write logfiles using this pattern *"${yyyy}/${MM}/${dd}/log${yyMMdd}.${####}.txt"*?

Create a new directory for each year, month, day and have the filenames contain the time and a running nummer (4 digits wide), for example *log192412.0001.txt* if a file size is exceeded (before a new day starts).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it myself:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="fileTarget" 
  fileName="${basedir}/${date:format=yyyy}/${date:format=MM}/${date:format=dd}/log${date:format=yyMMdd}.log"
  archiveFileName="${basedir}/${date:format=yyyy}/${date:format=MM}/${date:format=dd}/log${date:format=yyMMdd}.{####}.log"
  archiveAboveSize="1000000" />
```